# Laravel Vuetify - Appends all css inline

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I'm trying to use Vue on my laravel project.
And import vuetify for that project.

But it appends all css inline on the project.

My app.js is avobe:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

//import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import {store} from './store/store'

import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify' // path to vuetify export
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader



import Master from './Master'
import router from './router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)


Vue.config.productionTip = false;
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)){
        if(store.getters.loggedIn){
            next()
        }else{
            next({name: 'login'})
        }
    }else{
        if(store.getters.loggedIn){
            next({name: 'dashboard'})
        }else{
            next()
        }
    }

})
// use the plugin

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    store: store,
    vuetify,
    components: {Master},
    template: "<Master />"
});
```

My webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

And here's the how code compiles itself:

How can I use vuetify codes on "blabla.css" file?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean of use vuetify codes in blabla.css ?

Comment: i just want to compile all css inside a file, not inline html.

Answer (score 1):

remove your `vuetify.min.css` in your app.js

and move that in your app.scss like this

```
@import '~vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
```